Osgi framework bundle junit execution issue .junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
I am upgrading my application with latest equinox osgi version and getting below error while executing test cases. What I understood from multiple sources that this is related to org.junit.jupiter.api means junit-5 however my test cases return in junit-4. I have tried by adding org.junit.vintage dependency in my osgi based application but it didn’t work
Also I am getting this error where I used module as fragment
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 !MESSAGE Application error !STACK 1 org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests

Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: ClassSelector [className = ‘com.FailureClass’] resolution failed

Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Could not load class with name: com.FailureClass

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.FailureClass 

